# How to make festival speak on graphical login in xfce4?

Tags: xfce, autostart, festival

I've got Ubuntu Studio 16.04 with xfce4. 
My goal is to run festival, the speech generator, whenever I log in into the graphical desktop environment.

Making festival say something in the terminal works perfectly, for instance:

```
echo "got milk" | festival --tts
```

To achieve this, I tried this way:

opened the **session and startup** program, selected Application Autostart and clicked onto add. There I can input a command, which should start each time I log into xfce4, so they say.

[image]

However, when I log in into xfce4, no one is speaking.

Comment: You probably need to replace `festival` by `/usr/bin/festival` as the shell that executes the startup commands doesn't have a proper $PATH environment. Also, adding the command to `~/.bashrc` should work as well.

Comment: I have tried to put the whole path /usr/bin/festival, but it still will not work. For the second, I cant find .bashrc in ~

Comment: The full path name may be something other than `/usr/bin/festival` - check what it should be with `which festival`. As for `.bashrc` it is a hidden file - if you use Nautilus to find it, press Ctrl + H to view hidden files as well.

Comment: thanks, I understand, though the dot is not big, the bashrc still can hide behind it